# Compiling automation proxy with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

I am working on an automation server using mingw.

MIDL MyAutomationLib creates the files MyAutomationLib.h, MyAutomationLib_i.c, MyAutomationLib_p.c, and dlldata.c.

MyAutomationLib_i.c is compiled into my automation server, and MyAutomation_p.c is compiled into my automation proxy, which needs to be registered using regsvr32.exe.

When I am compiling the automation proxy, compilation fails because the header rpcproxy.h provided by MinGW is too old.

Does anyone know how to work around this problem?

I suppose a solution can be to use an older IDL compiler, but I am not able to find any information on this on mingw.org.

MIDL compiler version 7.00.0555

MinGW version -- installed with mingw-get 2 weeks ago (unable to find MinGW version..)

Comment: You could take a look at widl? http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Wine%20integration I haven't tested it myself though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this question myself. And the solution is simple, just compile the proxy with MSVC. The proxy doesn't have to be compiled with MinGW.